# Get the notification code from Listview Control checkboxes

Tags: listview, user-interface, mfc, listviewitem

I've implemented a ListView control with `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_INFOTIP` style. I've registered function to get notified from list view control items using.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Class, ParentClass)
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_GETINFOTIP,IDC_LIST2,OnClickCheckBox)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

My question is,  what notification code will be sent to parent when you select/de-select the checkbox in the item of ListView control..

What code need to be written to handle checkbox selection in the OnClickCheckBox() function ?

Kindly Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the item-changed-message and you have to find out, if the checkbox-state has been changed.

In the message map:

`ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, &CMyListView::OnLvnItemchanged)`

Event handler:

```
void CMyListView::OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    if(pNMLV->uNewState == 8192) // Item checked
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(pNMLV->uNewState == 4096) // Item unchecked
    {
        ...
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```