# only single selection in CListCtrl Checkbox in MFC

Tags: checkbox, mfc, clistctrl

In a MFC dialog, I have used a CListCtrl with checkbox. I want to disable multi checkbox selection , so that user can only select a single checkbox at a time. What is the best way to achieve this.I have done this

```
    void SomeClass::OnClickList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);


        int nSelectedItemIndex = -1;
        nSelectedItemIndex = m_ListCtrl.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);
        int nCount = m_ListCtrl.GetItemCount();    
        for(int nItem = 0; nItem < nCount; nItem++)
        {
            m_ListCtrl.SetCheck(nItem,false);
        }
        if(nSelectedItemIndex != -1)
            m_ListCtrl.SetCheck(nSelectedItemIndex,true);

        *pResult = 0;
    }
```

Somehow I think this method is not so proper and can be made better in other way. All suggesions are welcomed.

EDIT: UPDATE: after writing the code , everything is working but I am facing a new problem.
calling SetCheck() function inside OnItemChanged message handler function, it is calling the same function again, creating a recursion.Thus selection change is somehow slow. How to avoid this.Please help. ????

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have solved it . Now the checkbox and selection works at par. selecting checkbox selects the row and vice versa and one selection is possible. the code:

```
    void SomeClass::ResetAllCheckBox()
    {
        int nCount = m_ListCtrl.GetItemCount();
        for(int nItem = 0; nItem < nCount; nItem++)
        {
            m_ListCtrl.SetCheck(nItem,false);
        }

    }

    //Handler for ON_NOTIFY(NM_CLICK,...)
    void SomeClass::OnClickList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
        NMLISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;
        LVHITTESTINFO hitinfo;
        int nPosCB=-1,nPos=-1;
        hitinfo.pt = pNMListView->ptAction;

        //Make the hit test...
        nPosCB = m_ListCtrl.HitTest(&hitinfo);

        if(hitinfo.flags != LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON)
            return;
        ResetAllCheckBox();

        nPos = m_ListCtrl.GetNextItem(-1,LVNI_SELECTED);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemState(nPos, ~LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
        m_ListCtrl.SetItemState(nPosCB, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
        m_ListCtrl.SetSelectionMark(nPosCB);
        *pResult = 0;
    }


    //Handler for ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED,...)
    void SomeClass::OnItemchangedList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
        int nPos = -1;

        ResetAllCheckBox();

        nPos = m_ListCtrl.GetNextItem(-1,LVNI_SELECTED);
        if(nPos != -1)
            m_ListCtrl.SetCheck(nPos);

        int nCount = m_ListCtrl.GetItemCount();
        int nSelectedItemIndex = -1;
        for(int nItem = 0; nItem < nCount; nItem++)
        {
            if(m_ListCtrl.GetCheck(nItem)== 1)
                nSelectedItemIndex = nItem;
        }

        *pResult = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating the control make sure this style is used `LVS_SINGLESEL`.

It is passed in the CreateEx/CreateEx function. Also available from the resource editor (if control is added through it).

Comment: I have checked the listctrl properties from recource view. Single selection is set true.But still I can select multiple checkboxs at a time. May be I have misguided you in my question by saying multiple selection, actually it is a problem of multiple checkbox selection.

Answer (score 0):

I found a shorter solution. The idea is to detect if the user checked a checkbox. If it is the case, unchecked all the other checboxes, otherwise do nothing. Contrary to the answer by @egur, this solution does not check the checkbox upon selection of the row.

```
static void DisableAllItemsExcept(CListCtrl& ctrl, int indexToKeepChecked)
{
    for (int nItem = 0; nItem < ctrl.GetItemCount(); nItem++)
        if (nItem != indexToKeepChecked)
            ctrl.SetCheck(nItem, FALSE);
}

//in begin message map
//ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_SC_LIST, &CMyDlg::OnLvnItemchangedScList)

void CMyDlg::OnLvnItemchangedScList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    //detect if we checked a new element
    if ( (pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMLV->uNewState & 0x2000) && (pNMLV->uOldState & 0x1000) )
        DisableAllItemsExcept(m_lcList, pNMLV->iItem);  

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

The detection of state change was based on the following article : [Get the notification code from Listview Control checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606686/get-the-notification-code-from-listview-control-checkboxes). The values 0x1000 and 0x2000 do not seems to be defined anywhere in the header file, so maybe I'm using an undocumented feature.